# Python- Find missing Combinations in a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in a dataframe.
Similar to this

I know the year column has a set number of values: 2010-2013 so 4 different possible values.
I am trying to find the missing combinations of values.

Correct possible combinations

Nissan Altima 2010

Nissan Altima 2011

...

Chevy Silverado 2010

Chevy Silverado 2011

The Make always go with the model, I do not need to generate the unique combinations of those versions
NO TO

Nissan Silverado 2010

In this example I am missing Nissan Atima 2013 and Chevy Silverado 2010/2013.

I tried to go the route of iterating through the list of unique combinations but as my actual data set has thousands of unique elements it is not practical or time efficent.

```
data = [['nissan', 'altima', 2010], ['nissan', 'altima', 2011], ['nissan', 'altima', 2012] ['chevy', 'silverado', 2013], ['chevy', 'silverado', 2011], ['chevy', 'silverado', 2012]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['make', 'model', 'year])
```

also tried doing this but it does every combination

```
modelList= df['model'].unique()
makeList= df['make'].unique()
yearList= df['year'].unique()
combined = [modelList, makeList, yearList]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['modelList', 'makeList', 'yearList'], data=list(itertools.product(*combined)))
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following steps:

1. Get all the unique make-model combinations of the DataFrame, using the [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method.
2. Group the DataFrame by year, using the [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method.
3. Iterate over each year group, finding the make-model combinations that do not already exist in the group.

   The [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function allows one to combine the rows of two DataFrames. Then `.drop_duplicates()`can be used to remove the rows found in both (when setting `keep=False`).

Sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [['nissan', 'altima', 2010], ['nissan', 'altima', 2011], ['nissan', 'altima', 2012],
       ['chevy', 'silverado', 2013], ['chevy', 'silverado', 2011], ['chevy', 'silverado', 2012]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['make', 'model', 'year'])
```

Solution:

```py
# Find ALL the unique (make, model) combinations
unique_mkmod = df.drop_duplicates(["make", "model"])

# Group the DataFrame by year, considering the (make, model) fields from each
df_yeargroups = df.groupby(["year"])

results = None

# Iterate over every year group
for year, group in df_yeargroups:
    
    # Drop every combination in unique_mkmod that exists in the group, leaving only the ones that are not
    missing_mkmod = pd.concat([unique_mkmod, group]).drop_duplicates(["make", "model"], keep=False)
    
    # Change the year field for each remaining value to the group's year
    missing_mkmod["year"] = year
    
    # Add them to the end of the results set
    results = pd.concat([results, missing_mkmod])

# Final results
print(results)
```

With the following DataFrame as input:

```
     make      model  year
0  nissan     altima  2010
1  nissan     altima  2011
2  nissan     altima  2012
3   chevy  silverado  2013
4   chevy  silverado  2011
5   chevy  silverado  2012
```

It should produce the following output:

```
     make      model  year
3   chevy  silverado  2010
0  nissan     altima  2013
```